# What power cable to connect SATA drives to HP Proliant DL380 G6

Tags: sata, power, cable, hp-proliant

For a HP Proliant DL380 Gen6 server, I need to connect some SATA drives.

For the data part, I've bought a Mini SAS 4i SFF-8087 36P 36-Pin Male to 4 SATA 7-Pin Splitter Adapter Cable 2425#.  But what about for the power connection.  The motherboard is as [shown](https://c.76.my/Malaysia/hp-proliant-dl380-g6-motherboard-451277-001-496069-001-komputown-1611-03-komputown@3.jpg).  The available plug is as shown above the top of the RAM slots, a bit to the left.  What cable to buy?

Comment: Power comes from the power supply, not the motherboard.

Comment: If you care to find the specs and images of this server, you'd see that the power supply has no cables as in a desktop computer.  The only output I can see comes from those two connectors I've identified.  Does the power to the fans in your computer come from the power supply or from the motherboard?

Comment: If you want people to understand that, then you need to provide more information. I can correctly assume you aren't using the same configuration as the "specs" otherwise you wouldn't need a SATA power cable because the system comes with: "Standard (8) small form factor (SFF) hot-plug drive bays to support Serial attached
SCSI (SAS) and Serial ATA (SATA) drives" So, clearly we haven't been given all the information we need to understand what it is you are hooking up here. Your "stock" system has drive bays that you just slide hard drives in to and is fully capable of supporting SATA.